# How do I override the ActiveRecord association methods while still leveraging the cache?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to override ActiveRecord's association methods in some instances (related to caching the foreign keys of indirect `belongs_to` relationships. A typical example is a `QuoteStop` has a `Stop` and a `Stop` has a `PostalCode` and I want to cache the `postal_code_id` at the `QuoteStop` level also.

For this example, I'd like to add something like the following:

```
class QuoteStop
  attr_accessible :stop_id, :postal_code_id
  belongs_to :stop
  belongs_to :postal_code

  def postal_code_id
    self[:postal_code_id] or postal_code_id!
  end

  def postal_code_id!
    self.postal_code_id = stop.postal_code_id
  end

  def postal_code
    self[:postal_code_id] ? super : PostalCode.find(postal_code_id) if postal_code_id
  end

end

class Stop
  attr_accessible :postal_code_id
end
```

The problem is that this seems to bypass the cache for `postal_code`. For example, the following will result in n+1 queries where it should just result in 2.

```
QuoteStop.includes(:postal_code).limit(n).collect { |qs| qs.postal_code.name }
```

How do I use this technique without sacrificing the performance gains of ActiveRecord caching?

Comment: You don't appear to actually be overriding any methods there, but are instead merely delegating to an associated model.

Comment: the `def postal_code` replaces the getter that ActiveRecord would create from the `belongs_to` association. I'd like to have exactly the same behavior as would come usually come from calling `quote_stop.postal_code` if `quote_stop[:postal_code_id]` is not nil. If is it nil, I'd like to take over. In other words, I'd like `super` to cause the usual behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure your code is correct, and your code does not cache anything. I would write it as follows:

```
def postal_code_id 
  @postal_code_id ||= stop.postal_code_id
end

def postal_code
  if self.postal_code_id
    @cached_postal_code ||= PostalCode.find(self.postal_code_id)
  else
    super
  end
end
```

But I am not sure this will a big improvement. Because doing the `PostalCode.find` is exactly the same as doing the `stop.postal_code`.

So how do you think caching the `postal_code_id` will improve caching? Unless you are thinking along the lines of an identity map: where each `PostalCode` is only retrieved once. But then you would need to do something more elaborate on class level. Because any `QuoteStop` on itself (the instance) will never be aware of a `PostalCode` that was retrieved before.

Hope this helps.